# Trained vs randomly initialised cnn model. Difference in inference speed

Tags: ios, keras, conv-neural-network, coreml

We have 2 models written in Keras. We then convert them to coreml format and test the inference speed of each one on iPhone 7. The model architecture is the same for each of the two. The 1st model is trained on a set of images. the 2nd model's weights are randomly initialized. The number of params is the same for each model, however the speed (in fps) is different (21 vs 13 fps). How's this possible? Why is it so that the trained model is slower, despite the fact that the number of weights and the structure is the same?

Comment: Are you using the same sized inputs with both models?

Comment: It makes no sense to compare just one run of the code, as there are many factors that affect speed, take at least 10 runs and compute mean/std of the computation time, then you can start making comparisons.

Comment: yep, same sized inputs for both models. @MatiasValdenegro we did multiple runs (like 3-5) and calculated mean fps for each 30 seconds of inference. We got the same (mean) fps each time we run that same model. We still get very confusing results (i.e the trained model was slower than randomly initialised one).